# Is there a way to swipe left on a listview or recyclerview to show more options?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I want to create a listview or recyclerview of items, i want to be able to swipe to the left to display a "Delete", "Activate" or "Deactivate" options.

So essentially 2 options will be shown when i swipe, "Delete **and** "Activate" or "Deactivate" option.

The "Activate" or "Deactivate" will show depending on the value of my item.
i'm currently storing my items in a `HashMap<String, Marker>`

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Add a swipe listener to your RecyclerView, Check out the utility ItemTouchHelper. Source: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf

Comment: And in your onSwiped method create a dialog so that when you swipe an item it will open a dialog with options.